# HTML5 video fires pause event while seeked

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am designing an app which uses HTML 5 video. When I seek while the video is running "video pause" event is fired which in turns affect my logic for actions which has to happen during seeking. Is there a way by which I can remove this pause event or find that particular pause events which happen with seeking?

Answer (score 8):

You can use video element's `readyState` property to check whether the pause event fired when the user seeked or when the user paused.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var vidState = vid.readyState;   //when user hit the pause button, this value will be 4
```

Comment: How reliable is that?

Comment: it isn't reliable at all .. it doesn't work work on ios and firefox , when you make seeking , it also triggers pause , and readyState same 4  - for seeking and for pause

Answer (score 4):

@Jason Aller & @Qamer Sayeed are right.
If the user hits the pause button the ready state is 4.

In case of seeking, have an `onpause` listener for your video and inside that, check if the `vid.readyState` is 4(manually clicked!) otherwise if the pause event was initiated by the seek, the `vid.readyState` is 1.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you read though the HTML5 spec to understand how events work when seeking:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#seeking

Without a code sample it is hard to diagnose, but you could try testing the `seeking` event during your pause handler.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should know why the video pauses when you seek this with bar control. Actually when you seek, the video will be loading the timeline and will pause until it's done.

You can listen for the event `onPause`, then check if `video.seeking` was `true` and don't pause the video.

Like this code:

```js
var video = document.getElementById("videoId");
video.onpause = function() {
    if(video.seeking) {
        return
    }
    //else your action for pausing video :)
};
```